# Passing an C# array of structs with array of double member to C DLL by reference

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

We have the following code marshalling between c# and c dll. However, when print the value within the C dll function, the values associated with the double array properties are all 0.0000000.  I have put some in line comments for the code having problems.

Did we miss any thing to configure the marshalling behaviour?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MonteCarlo montecarlo = new MonteCarlo();
            montecarlo.RunMonteCarlo();
        }
    }
    class MonteCarlo
    {

        [DllImport("MonteCarloCUDA.dll")]
        public static extern int MonteCarloPrint([In, Out]PurchaseOrder[] purchaseorders, int length);

        public void RunMonteCarlo()
        {

            PurchaseOrder[] purchaseorders = new PurchaseOrder[3];

            purchaseorders[0] = new PurchaseOrder();
            purchaseorders[0].Value1 = "AAAAA";
            purchaseorders[0].Value2 = 0.111;
            purchaseorders[0].Value3 = new double[2]; // Assign the values to array of double
            purchaseorders[0].Value3[0] = 0.11111;
            purchaseorders[0].Value3[1] = 0.22222;

            purchaseorders[1] = new PurchaseOrder();
            purchaseorders[1].Value1 = "BBB";
            purchaseorders[1].Value2 = 0.222;
            purchaseorders[1].Value3 = new double[2];
            purchaseorders[1].Value3[0] = 0.33333;
            purchaseorders[1].Value3[1] = 0.44444;

            purchaseorders[2] = new PurchaseOrder();
            purchaseorders[2].Value1 = "CCC";
            purchaseorders[2].Value2 = 0.333;
            purchaseorders[2].Value3 = new double[2];
            purchaseorders[2].Value3[0] = 0.55555;
            purchaseorders[2].Value3[1] = 0.66666;

            int result = MonteCarloPrint(purchaseorders, purchaseorders.Length);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public unsafe struct PurchaseOrder
        {
            public string Value1;

            public double Value2;

            public double[] Value3; // Array of double member
        }
    }
}
```

// C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct PurchaseOrder 
{ 
   char* Value1; 
   double Value2; 
   double* Value3;
 };



__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MonteCarloPrint(PurchaseOrder *hostPurchaseOrders, int length)
{    
    printf("\nSize of PurchaseOrder: %d",sizeof(PurchaseOrder));

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {           
        printf("\n\nAddress: %u",hostPurchaseOrders+i);         
        printf("\nValue1: %s",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value1);
        printf("\nValue2: %f",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value2);
        printf("\nValue3[0]: %f",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value3[0]);
        printf("\nValue3[1]: %f",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value3[1]);

    }
}}
```

The print result from the C dll function

```
Size of PurchaseOrder: 24

Address: 13180880
Value1: AAAAA
Value2: 0.111000
Value3[0]: 0.000000 // No value are marshalled 
Value3[1]: 0.000000

Address: 13180904
Value1: BBB
Value2: 0.222000
Value3[0]: 0.000000
Value3[1]: 0.000000

Address: 13180928
Value1: CCC
Value2: 0.333000
Value3[0]: 0.000000
Value3[1]: 0.000000
```

Comment: Stratford, there have been multiple attempts to improve the formatting of your source code. Don't undo it. Obfuscating your code doesn't make you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Pack property from the [DllImport] declaration, it is wrong.  You are not using a #pragma pack directive in your C code, the default value for Pack is appropriate.  If it would have been in effect then your C code would have reported 16.

You are seeing 24 because there's 4 bytes of padding to align the double and 4 bytes of padding at the end of the structure to make the double align when the structure is used in an array.  4 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 4 = 24.  The packing in effect is 8, the default.

You can make it more efficient by swapping Value2 and Value3 to get a struct of 16 bytes, no padding necessary.  In case it matters.  That's what the JIT compiler does.

---

The next problem is tougher, the P/Invoke marshaller will marshal the embedded array as a SAFEARRAY.  You can solve that on the unmanaged side by using this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <objidl.h>

struct PurchaseOrder 
{ 
    char* Value1; 
    double Value2; 
    LPSAFEARRAY Value3;
    int fence;
};


extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MonteCarloPrint(PurchaseOrder *hostPurchaseOrders, int length)
{    
    printf("\nSize of PurchaseOrder: %d",sizeof(PurchaseOrder));

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {           
        printf("\n\nAddress: %u",hostPurchaseOrders+i);         
        printf("\nValue1: %s",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value1);
        printf("\nValue2: %f",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value2);
        double* arrayPtr;
        if (S_OK == SafeArrayAccessData((hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value3, (void**)&arrayPtr)) {
            printf("\nValue3[0]: %f", arrayPtr[0]);
            printf("\nValue3[1]: %f", arrayPtr[1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote the code using the C++ compiler, you may have to tweak.

Comment: Hi Hans, i removed the pack=1 from [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] but the problem still exists. The vlaue3 are populated by 0.00000 and size of purchaseorder is 24.